# Populate user accounts fields on web server with information in excel spreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, client-server, client-side, server-side

So here's the deal, I've been given an excel file containing a list of ~1600 users that all need to be updated on our web application server. On this list, there's their name, username file/exchange server, building, floor and all kinds of information. I am expected to update all of them manually a.k.a go in each of their individual profile and change every little field by hand, but there's no way in hell I'm doing that.

What I'm wondering is: is there a way to use PHP or a client side language to read that excel file and populate all of those user profiles automatically?

***Additionnal information:***

- The server is web based
- I could ask for an access to the server to run a PHP script
- All the information can be added through HTML if you specify a value="" but then you have to activate the "submit button":

`<input type="text" name="firstName" maxlength="30" tabindex="405" value="Mark" id="ES5_firstName" title="">`

Feel free to ask for any other needed information on the matter, I'll try to answer the best I can.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ read excell file and update records in database

Answer (score 1):

There are several PhP libraries that can read Excel. Another way to do it is to save the Excel sheet to CSV which can then easily be parsed by any programming language. You can then use a tool, such as Python Robot Framework, to read from the CSV file and populate the HTML forms and submit them one at a time.